# Is it possible to direct to an external website using variables in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I try to make every element in my app to direct to a website.
Let's say I want to search for an ID in google after clicking on this element.
I thought I can use HTML and just put

```
<a href=`https://www.google.com/search=${selected.ID}`>
```

but it does not treat `selected.ID` as a variable, but rather like a constant. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in React, you need to first get into templating mode, *then* you can put in normal JS data, so you probably just forgot the enclosing `{...}`:

```
render() {
  return <a href={ `https://www.google.com/search=${selected.ID}` }>;
}
```

If you don't, you're telling React's JSX algorithm to create `` <a href=`https://www.google.com/search=$something`> `` instead, which has two problems: it's literally using backticks instead of quotes, so that's an illegal HTML attribute, and it will include $ as part of the output, because it doesn't treat anything as JS code until it sees `{}`, which in this case it doesn't find until *after* the $ sign.